# Compare two dataframe and match the the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes
df1

| Questions | Answers |
| --- | --- |
| Was Abraham Lincoln the sixteenth President of the United States? | Yes |
| Did Lincoln sign the National Banking Act of 1863? | yes |
| Did his mother die of pneumonia? | no |
| How many long was Lincoln's formal education? | 18 months |
| When did Lincoln begin his political career? | 1832 |
| What did The Legal Tender Act of 1862 establish? | the United States Note, the first paper currency in United States history |
| Who suggested Lincoln grow a beard? | 11-year-old Grace Bedell |
| When did the Gettysburg address argue that America was born? | 1776 |
| Did Lincoln beat John C. Breckinridge in the 1860 election? | yes |
| •Was Abraham Lincoln the first President of the United States? | No |
| Did Lincoln start his political career in 1832? | Yes |
| Did Lincoln ever represent Alton & Sangamon Railroad? | Yes |
| Abraham_Lincoln Which county was Lincoln born in? | Hardin County |
| When did Lincoln first serve as President? | March 4, 1861 |
| Who assassinated Lincoln? | John Wilkes Booth |
| Did Lincoln win the election of 1860? | Yes |

I have another dataframe
df2

| Questions | Answers |
| --- | --- |
| Was Abraham Lincoln the sixteenth President of the United States? | No |
| Did Lincoln sign the National Banking Act of 1863? | yes |
| Did his mother die of pneumonia? | yes |
| How many long was Lincoln's formal education? | 18 months |
| When did Lincoln begin his political career? | 1832 |
| What did The Legal Tender Act of 1862 establish? | the United States Note, the first paper currency in United States history |
| Who suggested Lincoln grow a beard? | 11-year-old Grace Bedell |
| When did the Gettysburg address argue that America was born? | 1776 |
| Did Lincoln beat John C. Breckinridge in the 1860 election? | yes |
| •Was Abraham Lincoln the first President of the United States? | No |
| Did Lincoln start his political career in 1832? | Yes |
| Did Lincoln ever represent Alton & Sangamon Railroad? | No |
| Which county was Lincoln born in? | Hardin County |
| When did Lincoln first serve as President? | March 4, 1861 |
| Who assassinated Lincoln? | John Wilkes Booth |
| Did Lincoln win the election of 1860? | No |

I need to compare the first dataframe with the second and if the question and answer match then give output true else false
create a new dataframe in the following format

Result

| Question | Answer | is_match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ques1 | answer1 | false |
| Ques2 | answer 2 | true |
| Ques3 | answer3 | false |

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left or outer join and `indicator` parameter, for boolean compare by `both`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='is_match')
df['is_match'] = df['is_match'].eq('both')
```